# iTunesConnect iOS app on iPad?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

The iTunes connect site has a link for the native app, when you browse from an iOS app. On iPhone the download link works fine, however on iPad it opens the iTunes app (rather than the app store) and doesn't seem to ever load anything?

Does the app exist for iPad (or if you can install it, does it only work in 2x mode)? And is there another way to to get to the app page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on my iPad, and if you search the store, it seems to be hidden. If I search the store on my Mac in iTunes, it shows up though.

The direct link to it is http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect-mobile/id376771144?mt=8

[image: iTunes connect]

It also is a universal app, so it has an interface designed for the iPad.

Clicking this link on my iPad though still doesn't take me to the actual app. I think this may be a bug in the App Store. I can see it in iTunes on my computer and add it to my iPad that way.

After syncing it to my iPad through my computer, it launches fine, will connect, and looks good. The copyright on the app is 2010 though, so it looks like it hasn't been updated in a while (for example, no retina graphics on iPad). I did have a few times it threw an error saying it couldn't connect. I also don't have any apps in thee right now to test.